# Is there a way to override OnNavigatedTo in WPF on a page?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I know it exists on Silverlight but how about WPF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read [this part of the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx#PageLifetime)

Page navigation in WPF is different from Silverlight/Phone because you can opt -in for KeepAlive.

In short: use Loaded and Unloaded. KeepAlive will only influence whether or not a new instance is created.

**EDIT**

An alternative is to subscribe to the this.NavigationService.Navigated event but that does not get raised just for your page as far as I know.

Comment: Great article. Thanks for the link and your input.